# Is is possible to restrict a requesting domain at the application level?

Tags: security, http

I wonder how some video streaming sites can restrict videos to be played only on certain domains. More generally, how do some websites only respond to requests from certain domains.

I've looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields and saw the referrer field that might be used, but I understand that HTTP headers can be spoofed (can they?)

So my question is, can this be done at the application level? By application, I mean, for example, web applications deployed on a server, not a network router's operating system.

Any programming language would work for an answer. I'm just curious how this is done.

If anything's unclear, let me know. Or you can use it as an opportunity to teach me what I need to know to clearly specify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Headers regarding ip-information are helpful (because only a smaller portion is faked) but is not reliable. Usually web-applications are using web-frameworks, which give you easy access to these.

Some ways to gain source information:

- originating ip-address from the ip/tcp network stack itself: Problem with it is that this server-visible address must not match the real-clients address (it could come from company-proxy, anonymous proxy, big ISP... ).
- HTTP [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) Header, proxies are supposed to set this header to solve the mentioned problem above, but it also can be faked or many anonymous proxies aren't setting it at all.
- apart from ip-source information you also can use machine identifiers (some use the [User-Agent Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). Several sites for instance store this machine identifiers and store it inside flash cookies, so they can reidentify a recalling client to block it. But same story: this is unreliable and can be faked.

The source problem is that you need a lot of security-complexity to securely identify a client (e.g. by authentication and client based certificates). But this is high effort and adds a lot of usability problem, so many sites don't do it. Most often this isn't an issue, because only a small portion of clients are putting some brains to fake and access server.

[HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) is a different thing: It shows you from which page a user was coming. It is included by the browser. It is also unreliable, because the content can be corrupted and some clients do not include it at all (I remember several IE browser version skipping Referer).

Answer (score 0):

These type of controls are based on the originating IP address. From the IP address, the country can be determined. Finding out the IP address requires access to low-level protocol information (e.g. from the socket).

The referrer header makes sense when you click a link from one site to another, but a typical HTTP request built with a programming library doesn't need to include this.